# expr command syntax: string expression must be enclosed?

Tags: tcl

When I write the following script:

```
expr "a" ne "ab"
```

I get an error:

```
invalid bareword "a" 
in expression "a ne ab";
should be "$a" or "{a}" or "a(...)" or ...
```

I need to change it to `expr {"a" ne "ab"}`.

Yes, I know it is best practice to always brace-quote the expression arguments, but from syntax point of view, what is wrong in the above script?

I checked out the manual page, https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm,  it does not say there is syntax requirement here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the man page again, under "Operands". A string operand must be enclosed in double quotes or braces. Those quotes or braces must themselves be quoted in the invocation, otherwise the Tcl interpreter will strip them off before passing the arguments to the command.

If your invocation is

```
expr "a" ne "ab"
```

The command will get the argument list

```
a ne ab
```

which it can't process.

You could quote the quotes like this:

```
expr \"a\" ne \"ab\"
```

But you are much better off bracing it all up into a single argument. This will look neater, preserve your quotes, and avoid some other serious problems as well.

Comment: Yes, the key is interpreter strips off the double-quote so the expr command cannot see it.